# solve error: cannot access Publisher in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, javacompiler

I am getting this error while compilation of my code:

[image: error log]

Can anyone help me how to solve this error or what might be causing this error?

Edit1: Gradle file of the project . And also the error log is attached with the question above.please check it.

```
import com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {

compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.veblr.videomate"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 16
    versionName "1.0.0.8"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = true
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    resConfigs "en"
}

buildTypes {

    debug {
        jniDebuggable true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        ///shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'

        //Other parameters
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        renderscriptDebuggable false
        pseudoLocalesEnabled false
        zipAlignEnabled true

    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}
ext {
    roomVersion = '1.0.0'
    archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.0'
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/XXX'
    exclude 'META-INF/license/LICENSE.base64.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'

}

compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "12g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }
 }
afterEvaluate {
tasks.matching {
    it.name.startsWith('dex')
}.each { dx ->
    if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
        dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
    } else {
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    }
    }


   }
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    name 'Google'

}
     maven{  url  "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony"}
     maven {  url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
     }
    }
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:3.2.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector- 
impl:17.0.5"

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.27.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.27.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'


//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

implementation 'org.piwik.sdk:piwik-sdk:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'

// Room components
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
// Lifecycle components
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"

implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-rc02'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
apply plugin: 'digital.wup.android-maven-publish'
```

I think there is some problem with the java compiler and java sdk if so ,please let me know if that's the problem and how to solve it .

Comment: Will you please click on icon which is below of hammer icon, it will show you error detail, please share that details

Comment: It's already clicked and the error log is posted.

Comment: Did you tried invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: yes I did that but did not work.

Comment: @Sushrita could you please provide us your gradle files?

Comment: @Sushrita possible this error occurred from libraries implementation so we need your gradle files.

Comment: @Sushrita you need to do what suraj-vaishnav suggested in the first comment. Currently you have the big overview of the build - if you click that icon UNDER the one of the happer (the two grey boxes,  one behind another) that will give you the full build log.

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos uploaded the gradle file.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is problem with `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'` library , when I upgraded it in app/gradle , it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure in your project gradle buildscript you use **latest version**:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

And also try to update version of your libraries use **latest version**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:3.2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.5"

//noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.27.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.16'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'


//noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

    implementation 'org.piwik.sdk:piwik-sdk:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'

// Room components
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
// Lifecycle components
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"

    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'

}
```

Comment: I just upgraded to Android studio 3.4 and I can't compile the project. I'm keep getting the following error: `> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
e: error: cannot access Publisher
  class file for org.reactivestreams.Publisher not found
  Consult the following stack trace for details.
  com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.reactivestreams.Publisher not found`

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian make sure you have update all your dependencies to the latest version and try again.

Comment: I have same issue

Answer (score 0):

Run it with `--stacktrace` or `--info` or `--debug` to see more log outputs information from the terminal for example: `./gradlew compileDebugJavaWithJavac --debug`.

You wi be able to see more info on when and where it stopped the task and why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the Publisher class was belong to the RxJava library which was missing from my project so adding these two lines in my app/gradle file fixed the problem:

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.x.x'

Answer (score -1):

Try to update latest versions:

1. **RxJava**: [io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)
2. **RxAndroid**: [io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid)

Then, AndroidStudio -> File -> invalidate Cashes/Restart.

It helped me.