# Error: Android Gradle Plugin: Cannot Access Publisher

Tags: android, gradle

I am using **Android studio 3.4.2**

My build.gradle file as follows

I am getting this error and not able to run the app since I upgraded the android studio.

**I converted the code to androidx.**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    ext.realmVersion = '5.9.1'
    ext.googleServiceVersion = '4.2.0'
    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw/master"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:522bd9fc1d398753fed5134b6c4fe32cdae482be'  // Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android.
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        //  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-alpha13'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realmVersion"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$googleServiceVersion"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My App level build gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'RestrictedApi'
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }//this until  Google release a fix .bottomsheet super

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        dexInProcess = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude '.readme'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/README.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    def supportLibsVer = '1.0.0-beta01'

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$supportLibsVer"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta01"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation files('libs/DataVaultLib-2.3.3.13.jar')
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'

    //CardView

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'


    //Image Picker

    implementation 'com.github.jrvansuita:PickImage:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //For Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'

    //For Google Places

    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    //for event bus
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'


    //Room Database
    // Room
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'


    implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.3.3') {
        transitive = true;
    }
//
//    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I go through this question of stackoverflow [solve error: cannot access Publisher in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155092/solve-error-cannot-access-publisher-in-android-studio)

But it is not helpful.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem as soon as I upgraded to gradle 5.x (plugin 3.4+). In my case it was caused by two seemingly unrelated conditions:

1) Having a dependency on retrofit's adapter-rxjava2 plugin (without the accompanying 
`io.reactivex.rxjava2` dependencies):

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
```

2) Having a Room DAO with a query function that returns a List directly:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getUsers(): List<User>
}
```

The easiest solution was removing the adapter-rxjava2 dependency since I wasn't using it anymore anyway (and you likely aren't either since you don't include `io.reactivex.rxjava2` dependencies, hence the error).

I also found that changing the return type of the DAO function from `List` to `Array` also solved the problem for whatever reason. The actual underlying cause as to why these two things combine to cause this error is still a mystery to me, though.

Comment: Thanks! that helped a lot! In my case it was both the dependency you mentioned above and this one --> "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"