# How to use Room library?

Tags: java, android, android-room

In my application i want use database and for this i used **Room** library.
**I added this dependencies :**

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
```

But when added Database class show me show below error in **build tab** :

```
cannot access Publisher
```

**My Database class :**

```
@Database(entities = {TitlesEntity.class},version = 1,exportSchema = false)
public abstract class TitlesDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract TitlesDao titlesDao();
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: You may find the answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155092/solve-error-cannot-access-publisher-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

You are using obsolete dependencies; for Android Jetpack use:

```
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2"
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.2"
```

The "cannot access Publisher" likely comes from Android Architecture and/or it's RxJava bindings. Beside that, the question is too broad to provide an accurate answer - and there are enough tutorials.